# reading a file from a puppet erb template -- what is the working directory?

Tags: templates, puppet, erb

I have a bunch of config files with comments and various annotations that improve maintainability but the target application does not cope with this human oriented stuff.

I want to have an erb template that reads the file and transforms it into the format needed by the application.  The actual processing is straight forward the bit that I have not figured out is how to construct the file name so the template reads it from the `module/file` directory.

Put another way what is the working directory when a template is being processed by puppet?

Comment: can you provide the code that you tried and a sample for your template?

Comment: More information is needed before we could help you here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact need, but let me give you some hints:

If you're exploring how the puppet community uses `templates` you may want to google for the modules that use [templates](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_template.html) and get inspired from there (just paste the following [in Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=inurl%3Atemplates+https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fvoxpupuli&cad=h)):

```
inurl:templates https://github.com/voxpupuli
```

Regarding your question:

> what is the working directory when a template is being processed by puppet ?

The template is pulled from the module `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/<your-env>/modules/<your-module>/templates/<your-path>/<your-template>.erb` when a construction like the one bellow and the `.conf` file is generated. It may be using a temporary location for the generation (internally), but you don't have access and you shouldn't care:

```
file { "/etc/<your-path-to-your-conf>/<some-filename>": 
   path => "/etc/tomcat/testing/$name.conf", 
   content => template("template('#{module_name}/<your-path>/<your-template>.erb'),"), 
}
```

*Note*: Most the examples (e.g. [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/puppet/puppet_template.htm) or [here](https://codingbee.net/puppet/puppet-modules-the-templates-folder)) you find, hardcode the `template` path to your module, but you can also use [`#{module_name}` as variable](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/lang_facts_and_builtin_vars.html)